# How to map configuration objects to java object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have a spring boot application which is using a spring cloud config. 
How can i map a configuration element with some java object.

My config is something like this:

```
clients:
- id         : 1
  name: client 1
  groups    : [a,b]

- id         : 2
  name: client 2
  groups    : [a]
```

And my java object is:

```
public class ClientInfo {
  private String clientId;
  private List<String> profiles;

  public ClientInfo(String clientId, List<String> pips) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.profiles = pips;
  }
  public String getClientId() {
    return clientId;
  }

  public void setClientId(String clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
  }

  public List<String> getProfiles() {
    return profiles;
  }

  public void setProfiles(List<String> profiles) {
    this.profiles = profiles;
  }
}
```

I want to map my configuration with List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to configure configuration properties in to java Object,

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "clients")
public class ClientInfo {

private String id;
private String name;
private List<String> groups;

public String getId(){ return id;}

public String getName(){ return name;}

public List<String> getGroups(){ return groups;}

}
```

Check following for example http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Inject this class in another class :

```
@Autowired
private ClientInfo clientInfo;
```

The above auto wiring will not work if the class is instantiated using "new operator".

Comment: Thanks!! will try it

Comment: How should I inject this configuration? using @Autowired didn't worked.

Comment: @AnkurGupta I edited my answer please check how you are instantiating the class.Please post the code so that we can help furthur

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the reason why it was not working. 
All that was needed is to have another class which contains a list of ClientInfo and have @EnableConfigurationProperties and @ConfigurationProperties annotations on it. This is because "clients" in my configuration is a list. After this change we can use @Autowired annotation to inject the configuration.